# How do you solve intellisense conflict between two definitions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

When there are two definitions of globally accessible types, `Intellisense` gets confused. So in the situation I'll describe, even if my solution is transpiling fine, I constantly see errors in Intellisense because there is indeed two elements with the same name that are globally accessible: `Leaflet`'s `Map`, from `L` namespace: `L.Map`, and Map, from `core-js` (a small library of 1 million downloads per week that has no tag on SO).

Look how strange it is in the attached picture: I define a `Leaflet` `L.Map`, then when trying to pass it to the `addTo` method of my marker, it complaints that the map should actually have the `Map<Object, Object>` type, which is absolutely false.

Anything I can do to avoid this situation in `Visual Studio 2015` with `Typescript`?

[image: Intellisense confused between a Dictionary map and a Leaflet map]

Comment: That's incredibly strange - the fact that the Leaflet `Map` type is within a namespace should stop the compiler from mixing the two up. Which sets of type definitions are you using for the libraries, the ones off DefinitelyTyped?

Comment: Yes, DefinitelyTyped, both for `core-js` and `Leaflet`. This is the weirdest part of the problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, it actually complains that you have an `L.Map` in your `map` variable when `Map<Object, Object>` was expected.

Comment: Which is ideally not what it should do. It's the addTo method of the Leaflet Marker to add the marker to a map. So if I understand correctly, internally, the method constructor is dropping the namespace of the parameter (L) and expects a Map, and since the CoreJS Map is globally available, then it's expecting a 'Dictionary' map instead of an L.Map. I'll see if the Leaflet marker method definition in DefinitelyTyped could be fixed by explicitely prefixing with the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The Leaflet `Map` will not conflict with the global `Map` *unless someone explicitly brought it out to the global scope*:

```
// something like; 
import Map = L.Map;
```

## More

To be extra sure try another IDE (e.g. http://alm.tools/ )